# Player very low on chips, can't pay Ante+BB. What happens?

Tags: rules, no-limit

Let's say three players, NLHE. Ante/SB/BB = 100/1000/2000.

Player 1 (BB): 50 chips left

Player 2 (Button): 10,000 chips

Player 3 (SB) : 10,000 chips

100 chips Ante to be paid by everyone - but Player 1 can't pay, so he/she is all-in. 3 x 50 chips go into main pot and 2 x 50 chips go into a side-pot between players 2 and 3.

Now the blinds: player 3 pays the small blind, which goes into the side-pot. player 1 would have to pay the big blind, but is all-in and can't pay.

Does player 2 now still have to "call" a full big blind of 2000, although nobody actually posted that amount?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, as I understand. Player 2 can either call the amount of the big blind or if they make a raise, they will have to raise to the smallest allowable amount. In this case that would be the twice the size of the big blind (4000).

Answer (score 2):

Yes he is forced to call the big blind(or raise) in order to play. The only thing is the remaining blinds and bets from now on go to the side pot. So basically player 1 can only watch the game and learn how his opponents play from an "audience" point of view (without knowing their cards) simply seeing their strategies unfold